# problems retaining original backslashes when passing url 

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an application which parses strings and passes them via jQuery to a popup window. Some of the strings I am passing contain a field for web addresses OR internal C: drive locations. When I pass the string to the window, the backslash ("\") from the windows path is being stripped out (the web addresses using the forwardslash is, of course, no problem. I am trying to pass these strings as links, so the user can just click on the link and off they go. Obviously, if the backslashes are stripped, the link does not work. How the heck do I test for this? I have tried a few simple regexes that don't work.

EDIT:  The strings that I am parsing come from a Sharepoint list of applications, and I have no control over their format, they are simply entered into the list as "\drive\then\the\path\to\the\file".  My understanding is that I need to check to see if there is a backslash, then escape it by adding another backslash. But how?

EDIT 2:  Good to know that I was on the right track.  From what I had read on the internets, I had figured it was something along this line.  However, I still can't get this to work. Maybe you folks could help me out....

I have grabbed the field from the sharepoint list like this (sharepoint stores field names with a prefix of 'ows_':

```
var devPath = "<a class='h_link' href='"+$(this).attr('ows_DEVPathURLServer')+"'>"+$(this).attr('ows_DEVPathURLServer')+"</a>";
```

This works great for web URLs, as stated.

So then I messed around with doing a .replace(/\/g,'\\');, but it won't run. So then I thought I would try:

```
      var unregged = $(this).attr('ows_DEVPathURLServer');
      var regged = unregged.toString().split('\\').join('\\\\');
      alert(regged);
      var devPath = "<a class='h_link' href='"+regged+"'>"+regged+"</a>";
```

Just to break down my thought process. Doesn't work. What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: You could url encode (window.encodeURIComponent) the paths before you pass them.

Comment: As a fairly big newb (read 'student'), I am unfamiliar with this. How would I go about this?

Comment: Consider changing title of question (and maybe tags too) to represent what question is about. Don't really see how it's related to "regex troubles"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply check if this is location that is "local" and convert it to [File URI scheme](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) prior to passing it further.

Something like this may do the trick:

```
var localPathRegex = /^\\(\w)\\/i;
if (localPathRegex.test(url)){
  url = url.replace(localPathRegex, 'file:///$1:/').replace(/\\/g, '/');
}
```

This should convert `\d\then\the\path\to\the\file` to `file:///d:/then/the/path/to/the/file`

Comment: Tried this, thanks, still doesn't work. All slashes are removed. Insted of  the original '\\d\path\to\my\file'  I still get  '\dthenpathtomyfile' which is what I get when I don't try anything at all......

Comment: @mrwienerdog, I've made a mistake in the initial code sample, that should be fixed now

Answer (score 3):

In order to "double" each backslash you can do:

```
myString.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\')
```

Please note than each time you see two backslash in the code, it's actually one since we need to escape them in our code as well.

the `g` means Global replacement, so if  you have several \ they will all be replaced.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a faster, regex-less, one line solution:

```
myString.split('\\').join('\\\\');//replaces all backslashes with double backslashes.
```

Using regexp here is just overkill...

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your backslashes with another backslash. Your passed url would look something like this:

c:\\mydrive\\MyFolder

Comment: Thanks Levi. I edited my post, as I think I wasn't quite as clear as I should have been.